# Trouble creating a diamond in svg

Tags: svg

I am trying to create a baseball diamond via svg.

Here is what I have
[Baseball SVG](https://codepen.io/MikeIsHere/pen/PoQmagj)

But the diamond portion does not look correct to me, the left side seems a little pushed out or elongated.  But the math seems to work out

P0: 35,83 and P2: 35,41 have the same X-coordinate and have a Y-coordinate 42 pixels apart (Home Plate and Second Base)

P1: 54,58 and P3: 12,58 have the same Y-coordinate and have a X-coordinate 42 pixels apart (First Base and Third Base)

So the math seems correct but it still looks off

Comment: Two things. I would use a bigger scale, let's say 10x bigger, to have more reference points without the need to use decimal places, and later scale it down. And 2, Why don't you use graphic software like Inkscape, at least for the diamond?

Comment: Your diamond is drawn here: `<polygon points="350,830 540,580 350,410 120,580" />`. If the top and bottom points have an x coordinate of 350, then the points on the left and right sides need to be the same distance from the line x=350. But they're not. The average of 540 and 120 is 330, not 350. That's why the diamond looks wrong.